# react javascript arrow function without arrows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, slate

I don't understand how this can work in javascript

```
renderMarkButton(type, icon) {
```

it looks like an arrow function, but without the arrows. Here's the context:

```
class HoverMenu extends React.Component {

  renderMarkButton(type, icon) {
    const { editor } = this.props
    return (
      <div className="editorButton" 
            onMouseDown={event => this.onClickMark(event, type)}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon color="#666" active={isActive} 
            className="editorButton" icon={icon}  />
        </div>
    )
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderMarkButton('bold', {...faBold})}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm also confused by the

```
  const { editor } = this.props
```

which comes from Slate, I believe. I would have expected this.props to be {type,icon} in this case.

Comment: `renderMarkButton` is a class method, and `const { editor } = this.props` is using 'destructuring' to retrieve `this.props.editor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow and bound methods are useful for passing them as callbacks to be called later:

```
<Component onClick={this.clickHandler}/>
```

This isn't the case for `renderMarkButton` because it's called in a place where it's used with correct `this` context:

```
this.renderMarkButton('bold', {...faBold})
```

`renderMarkButton` is class prototype method. It doesn't work like arrow function because it isn't bound to the context. Calling it with wrong context would result in error because there would be no `this.props` object:

```
const unboundFunction = this.renderMarkButton;
unboundFunction('bold', {...faBold});
```

Answer (score 8):

Regarding your questions:

1. `renderMarkButton(type, icon) {` is just the es6 class syntax:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
2. `const { editor } = this.props` is called "destructuring". You can read about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

hope that helps :)

Comment: *es6 class syntax*, its actually a method of a class

Comment: methods inside the class dont need the function keyword.

Comment: @breytex how he can access `this.props` inside that `renderMarkButton`?

Comment: @MaheerAli `this.props` and `this.state` are globally available in each react component. Read more here :) https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @breytex Thanks

Comment: For the es6 syntax, I also found a page that gives syntax specific to react (no constructor, no new keyword...): https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a special syntax according to new `class` keyword which will let you create classes.

Basically, those are methods of that specific class and you can't define any other method outside of the class using that specific syntax.

For more information, [consider MDN as your best partner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).